# How to stop the execution of the calling parent method in c#?

Tags: c#

The calling parent method:

```
public void Script()
{
    string str = "some text";
    var someText = !CheckStr(str);
    if (someText)
    {
        return;
    }

    str = "some other text";
    var someOtherText = !CheckStr(str);
    if (someOtherText)
    {
        return;
    }

    str = "some other other text";
    var someOtherOtherText = !CheckStr(str);
    if (someOtherOtherText )
    {
        return;
    }

    // ...continue
}
```

The method that is being called:

```
public bool CheckStr(string str)
{
    if (str == "error")
    {
        return false;
    }

    // ...additional checks

    return true;
}
```

Is there a way that if `CheckStr()` returns `false` that it also stops the `Scripts()` method from further executing?

Right now I have to do a bunch of `if` checks in the `Script()` method, it feels a bit like I'm repeating myself with the `if statement` doing the same thing after each `CheckStr()`. It would be better if the `CheckStr()` halts te execution of `Script()`. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why you overwrite the contents of `str` each time instead of having an array you iterate through?

Comment: In general, a method should not **impose** a workflow change on its caller (<-- opinion). However, you might consider using exceptions instead if this is really what you want to do. You probably need to catch the exception in the caller though, so some change is necessary.

Comment: Also, consider naming your methods appropriately. "CheckStr" is akin to me seeing a something light up in the dashboard of my car, and then upon reading the instruction manual for my car it says "Check engine". That doesn't help. All **I** know is that the engine is supposed to be there, and it still is. Make sure the method name accurately describes what the method is supposed to do. For instance, if the method name would be "IsStringValid", then I would assume it would return true or false, however if it was named "AssertStringIsValid", I would actually expect a hard crash if it isn't.

Comment: `CheckStr` is not the real name I made a sample example to illustrate problem as easy as I can. I can't get around by using an array. I think indeed exceptions might perhaps be the only solution if I want to prevent a bunch of `if statements.`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can throw a exception.

It will interrupt calling "parents" (and their "parents") until a execption-handler is somewhere (try-catch block).
Just google for exception-throwing.

Comment: Throwing an exception to handle code flow, eek and IMHO is anti-pattern. I would have suggested restructuring/refactoring the current code...